# Setting up SVN for Xcode

Tags: xcode, macos

We are currently about to setup one of our servers to be a SVN server and I want to know if there is anything we need to bare in mind before doing it.

We need it primarily for Xcode and Objective C code.

Will a server running Linux work with Xcode running on a mac?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes it will work here is how to set up [ubuntu](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Subversion) for such a use case.

Comment: How much space do I need for SVN?